# Set theory -- union of all permutation sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose there is an ambient set $D$ and an ordered index list $<1,2,...,n>$. We assign each pair of different indices $<i,j>(i \neq j \in \{1,2,...,n\})$ a subset $S_{i,j}\subseteq D$ while $S_{i,j}$ and $S_{j,i}$ are complements of each other in $D$. Also, for any three or more indices $<i,j,k>$, we have $(S_{i,j}\cup S_{j,k}) \supseteq S_{i,k} \supseteq (S_{i,j} \cap S_{j,k})$.

For any permutation $<i_1,i_2,...,i_n>$ of $<1,2,...,n>$, we define the set 
\begin{align}
A_{i_1,i_2,...,i_n} = \cap_{i,j (i \neq j \in \{i_1,i_2,...,i_n\})} S_{i,j}
\end{align}
where the index of $i$ in the permutation should be less than that of $j$, which results in $n(n-1)/2$ $S_{i,j}$. For example, if $n=3$, $A_{2,1,3}=S_{2,1}\cap S_{2,3} \cap S_{1,3}$.

The number of permutation for list $<1,2,...,n>$ is $n!$. Let $A$ be the union of all possible permutation $A_{i_1,i_2,...,i_n}$. I want to proof whether $A=D$ or with what conditions $A=D$ satisfies.

Here I give an example when $n=3$, I want to generalize it to arbitrary $n$ but I stuck here. There are six permutation when $n=3$. 
\begin{align}
A_{1,2,3} \cup A_{1,3,2} & = (S_{1,2} \cap S_{1,3} \cap S_{2,3}) \cup (S_{1,2} \cap S_{1,3} \cap S_{3,2}) \\
& = S_{1,2} \cap S_{1,3} \cap D = S_{1,2} \cap S_{1,3}
\end{align}
Similarly, we have 
\begin{align}
A_{2,1,3} \cup A_{2,3,1} = S_{2,1} \cap S_{2,3} \\
A_{3,2,1} \cup A_{3,1,2} = S_{3,2} \cap S_{3,1}
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
A = (S_{1,2} \cap S_{1,3}) \cup (S_{2,1} \cap S_{2,3}) \cup (S_{3,2} \cap S_{3,1})
\end{align}
According to the kind guy who states in ([Union of all possible intersections of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395980/union-of-all-possible-intersections-of-sets)), $A=D$ happens when $S_{1,2}\cap S_{2,3} \cap S_{3,1}=\varnothing$ and $S_{1,2} \cup S_{2,3} \cup S_{3,1} = D$. Fortunately, these two conditions hold, because according to the premise, we have 
\begin{align}
(S_{1,2}\cup S_{2,3}) \supseteq S_{1,3} \supseteq (S_{1,2}\cap S_{2,3})
\end{align}
Also, $S_{1,3}$ and $S_{3,1}$ are complements of each other in $D$. As a result, $(S_{1,2}\cap S_{2,3} \cap S_{3,1}) \subseteq (S_{1,3} \cap S_{3,1}) = \varnothing$, and $(S_{1,2} \cup S_{2,3} \cup S_{3,1}) \supseteq (S_{1,3}\cup S_{3,1}) = D$. Therefore, when $n=3$, $A=D$ holds.

However, when I try to generalize the proof to $n=4$ by this kind of deduction, I've got a problem, for example, I can obtain 
\begin{align}
A = (S_{1,2} \cap S_{1,3} \cap S_{1,4}) \cup (S_{2,1} \cap S_{2,3} \cap S_{2,4}) \cup (S_{3,1} \cap S_{3,2} \cap S_{3,4}) \cup (S_{4,1} \cap S_{4,2} \cap S_{4,3})
\end{align}
But I do not know what conditions could make $A=D$ hold, I wonder is there any theorem stating this problem, or is there any easier way to proof my problem. Hope someone could help or give some hints, thanks.